# Changing inner radius of D3 arc when using ArcTween

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to animate a pie chart using D3, meaning animate the start angle from 0 to some X angle. I have the following code:

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(pie([0, 0]))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return "#314965" })
  .attr("d", arc.endAngle(colorCounter == 0 ? 2 * Math.PI : 0.5))
path = d3.select(path[0][0]);

setInterval(function() {
  path.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, Math.random() * 0.314);
}, 1500);


//Animation tween function
function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
  transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc(d);
    };
  });
}
```

This animates fine, however, the arc that animates doesn't have the same inner or outer radius as the original one. I'm suspecting that the problem is when I return arc(d), the radii got reset to default. If that's the case, I'm not sure how to set them. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: How do you define `arc` ?